# ufw - How can I open up a port to a range of ip's (UB 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, ufw

i wonder if you can help me. I want to open up a specific range of ips to port 22, e.g
from 32.46.23.113 to 32.46.23.126, how would I do this with UFW?

I've had a look at subnet masking and have seen that i can open up 32.46.23.113/24 but my understanding is that this would allow traffic from 32.46.23.127-32.46.23.255, which I don't want ideally

Your help and any explanation you can give as to how this works is much appreciated.